# How to detect when an iOS app is terminated by the user from the multi-tasking UI without using 'Location updates' capability

Tags: ios, core-location, appdelegate, ios-background-mode, ios-lifecycle

How to detect when an iOS app is terminated by the user from the multi-tasking UI without using 'Location updates' capability. I know from the Apple's documentation that 'applicationWillTerminate' function in AppDelegate is not called in such a scenario.
[App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW7)

> Suspended apps receive no notification when they are terminated; the system kills the process and reclaims the corresponding memory. If an app is currently running in the background and not suspended, the system calls the applicationWillTerminate: of its app delegate prior to termination. The system does not call this method when the device reboots.
>
> In addition to the system terminating your app, the user can terminate your app explicitly using the multitasking UI. User-initiated termination has the same effect as terminating a suspended app. The app’s process is killed and no notification is sent to the app.

But when we set **'Location updates'** capability, **allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true** and **startUpdatingLocation()** then the function 'applicationWillTerminate' is called. My question is that is there any workaround or any other capability where 'applicationWillTerminate' is called without using 'Location updates'.